# How to solve for each loop compiler error in c++?

Tags: c++

Hi I am using this as my compiler

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

and then when I try to compile for each loop with
***g++ 2dForEach.cpp*** it throws this error

```
2dForEach.cpp:9:14: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

It only happened when I try to compile on terminal using ***g++***.

It works completely fine when I try to compile directly on **Xcode**.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to tell the compiler the version of C++ that you want to use.  You'll need to consult the `g+++` man page.  The range based `for` loop was put into C++ 11 and later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it actually told you.

Compile with

```
G++ -std=c++11 2dForEach.cpp
```

EDIT: Sorry, mis-copied arg :)